# Подскажите книгу по объектно ориентированному программированию

Tags: книги

Без привязки к языку. Просто хорошую книжку по теме

Comment: Хороший автор Герберт Шилдт, у него по C# хорошая книга, точно название не помню.

Comment: нет, скорее наоборот! шлдта вообще не надо читать! 

шилдт, один из тех авторов которых заслуженно ругают по всему инету...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Конечно же Банда четырех - Приёмы объектно -ориентированного проектирования ([PDF](http://modis.ispras.ru/Lizorkin/private/patterns.pdf))

Ещё есть отличная книга Грэди Буч - Объектно-ориентированный анализ и проектирование с примерами приложений([Ozon](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/3905587/))

Comment: Это уже следующая ступенька, так сказать уже использование ООП. Меня же интересует ООП как парадигма программирования.

Comment: книга Грэди Буч - во, это наверное то, что нужно

Comment: @Danolovonline - На будущее возьмите список [книг][1]

[1]: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AnOjkjHaHxMYdGN6OWhQaThJaFdMRjVXYXBfdXJCaFE&usp=drive_web#gid=0

Comment: @ua6xh охо спасибо! +1

Comment: @Danilovonline "Банда четырёх" -- http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0_%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%80%D1%91%D1%85 . А книга http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns по словам специалистов -- сборник рецептов по борьбе с недостатками C++ (и, возможно, java)

Comment: @alexlz - ну что вы в самом деле, все прекрасно понимают о какой [банде четырёх][1] идет речь (вторая в списке).

[1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0_%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%80%D1%91%D1%85_(%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Comment: @ua6xh ну список далеко не полный. Этих банд много больше. Одна даже разработала протокол ликвидации колец в системах бриджей/свичей. 

А касательно Буча, так есть рекомендации от D.Jelovic (http://www.jelovic.com/misc/people.htm ):

    Robert C. Martin
    Previous editor of the C++ Report. Teaches good object-oriented design and doesn't sell you any bullshit, unlike Grady Booch. If you want to do good object-oriented design, read the following articles from his website: